# HDD MBR problems?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd, mbr

So, I installed W10 on an SSD with an HDD also installed. This HDD is WILDLY noisy, so I'm swapping it out for a different, quieter one.

Now, I plug the new HDD in, so there are now three drives and try to initialize it in disk management, but I get an error: "The device is not ready."

So I try to remove the noisy HDD and swap it with the new HDD and W10 won't boot, despite the fact that it was installed on the SSD?

What do I do here?

Comment: Sounds like the boot partition (which is different then the system partition) is on the HDD not the SDD

Comment: @Ramhound do you have a recommended course of action? Is it possible to rebuild the boot partition on the new HDD?

Comment: You will need to reinstall Windows on the SSD, after assuring that you have enough available space and after having taken the necessary precautions.

Comment: @harrymc I copied the boot partition from the HDD to the SSD, after resizing the OS partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the boot partition from the noisy hard drive to the SSD, so that it can boot to windows independently, this is pretty easily done with AOMEI Partition Assistant or MiniTool Partition Wizard.

After this is done, get the new, quieter HDD and create a partition, so that the drive is initialized. Now, copy the contents of the old, noisy HDD to the new, quiet HDD.

Answer (score 0):

If copying system partition to SSD doesn't fix the issue, you can try using Windows installation media or recovery disc to repair startup. This kind of device could fix system problems that are caused by lacking boot files.

Actually, the OS partition is called boot partition while the EFI system partition or System Reserved Partition is called system partition.